# How do I set the buffer value to zero?

Tags: c++, pointers, memset

after I memory copy the value from GPU to CPU, how do I set the value to 0 with the same length? For example, cpubuff here.

```
cudaMemcpyAsync(
      (void*) cpubuff_, 
      (const void *) src_, 
      (size_t) buflen_, 
      (cudaMemcpyKind) cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost, 
      (cudaStream_t) *stream)
```

Comment: but cpubuff_ here is on the host.

Comment: then, `memset(cpubuff_, 0, buflen_);`  (This is not really a CUDA programming question)

Comment: Thanks Robert. (Yep.... I removed cuda tag.... )

Answer (score 2):

If you want to zero out a buffer on the host, then you can call memset.

```
memset(cpubuff_, 0, buflen_);
```

Assuming you don't need the async functionality.